# Doctrine 2 can't use nullable=false in manyToOne relation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

An `User` has one `Package` associated with it. Many users can refer to the same package. `User` cannot exists without a `Package` defined. `User` should own the relation. Relation is bidirectional, so a `Package` has zero or more users in it.

These requirements lead to `ManyToOne` relation for `User` and `OneToMany` relation of `Package` in Doctrine 2. However `package_id` in `user` table (that is foreign-key) allows `null` values. I've tried setting `nullable=false` but command:

```
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities DL --path="src" --no-backup
```

Says that there is no attribute `nullable` for the relation `ManyToOne`. **What i'm missing?**

```
class User
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Package", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $package;

}

class Package
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="package")
     */
    private $users;

}
```

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Use the JoinColumn annotation on your ManyToOne relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Package", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="package_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $package;
```

The ManyToOne itself cannot be nullable, because it doesn't relate to a specific column. The JoinColumn on the other hand identifies the column in the database. Thus, you can use "normal" attributes like nullable or unique!

Comment: Thanks, i've tried but unfortunately the column `package_id` is still flagged as Null - Yes, Default - NULL. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, a double quote completly break the thing. That is `nullable="false"` is wrong!

Comment: Did you try deleting the database entirly and creating it new? I just had a look at my database (using the same JoinColumn annotation as mentioned above) and it's flagged as NotNull!

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd been wondering why I couldn't make it `@ORM\Column(nullable=true)` to make my manytoone nullable!

Comment: If you configured the right option and you still see your database column with the wrong value, remember to clear metadata cache for Entity Manager. On Symfony, you can use `console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` command

Answer (score 3):

Only `@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)` is required