# Create relationnal entitiy on Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I would like to save my users search on my website. Thaht's why i have a Class User and i would like to create Search Class.
I have done that :

```
class Search 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->searched_date = new \Datetime(); 
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
    private $id;


    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="test\UserBundle\Entity\User")
    */
    private $user;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="termsearch", type="string", length=255, nullable="true")
    */
    private $termsearch;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="goodtitle", type="string", length=255, nullable="true")
     */
    private $goodtitle;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="searched_date", type="datetime")
    */
    private $searched_date;



    /**
     * Set termsearch
     *
     * @param text $termsearch
     */
    public function setTermsearch($termsearch)
    {
        $this->termsearch = $termsearch;
    }

    /**
     * Get termsearch
     *
     * @return text 
     */
    public function getTermsearch()
    {
        return $this->termsearch;
    }

    /**
     * Set searched_date
     *
     * @param datetime $searchedDate
     */
    public function setSearchedDate($searchedDate)
    {
        $this->searched_date = $searchedDate;
    }

    /**
     * Get searched_date
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getSearchedDate()
    {
        return $this->searched_date;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param test\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function setUser(\test\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return test\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set goodtitle
     *
     * @param text $goodtitle
     */
    public function setGoodtitle($goodtitle)
    {
        $this->goodtitle = $goodtitle;
    }

    /**
     * Get goodtitle
     *
     * @return text 
     */
    public function getGoodtitle()
    {
        return $this->goodtitle;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And i would like to insert like that :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$user = $em->getRepository('TestUserBundle:User')->find($currentuser->getID());     
$search = new Search();
$search->setUser($user);
$search->setTermsearch($termsearch);
$search->setGoodtitle($goodtitle);
$em->persist($search);
$em->flush();
```

Unfortunately i have this error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (500 Internal Server Error)
```

And in the stack we can found that :

```
INSERT INTO s_search (user_id, termsearch, goodtitle, searched_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ({"1":"c2c","2":"C2C Down The Road","3":{"date":"2012-10-31 00:18:47","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}})
```

I don't know how i can create this class Search...
Thank for for you help !

Comment: For some reason your code snippet is not correctly formatted here. Would you mind fixing that? It may help us to figure out the code and then help with your question.

Comment: In effect, that's done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `@ORM\Id` from the `$user` as @ManyToOne mapping reference does not require a type. See [Doctrine's Annotation Reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) for details. Doctrine takes care of the correct column type to hold the reference to another entity.

Make also sure that your User query really returns a valid `$user`. If it's possible that Search does not have `$user`, use `@JoinColumn` annotation to claim the column nullable. See another SO question [Doctrine 2 can't use nullable=false in manyToOne relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674397/doctrine-2-cant-use-nullable-false-in-manytoone-relation)